# Can a thread be sown around tzitzis to keep them hanging in the correct manner?

Tags: tzitzis

According to Mishnah Berurah 11:15, the mechaber writes: "Yesh omrim that one must make a point of hanging the tzitzis to the length of the talis".  MB 73 writes this is l’chatchila, but b’diavad, there is no insistence on it.

Nowadays, it seems that the tzitzis are tied tightly to the talis so that they won’t slip from the length of the talis.  Chabad solves the problem by making two holes.

My question is whether it would be permissible to fasten the tzitzis to the length of the talis by means of a thread that would just encircle the tztizis and keep them secured to a point along the length of the talis.  This would be done after the tzitzis have been tied. The purpose of the thread would be to anchor the tzitzis to the talis so they don’t drop down.

In the picture, I've drawn where a thread could be sewn to just anchor the tzitzis in one spot.  The thread would go around the tzitzis and would not interfere in any way with the tzitzis themselves.  It would simply serve to keep the tzitzis in one place and prevent gravity from pulling the tzitzis down.

[image: Talis with tzitzis anchored by thread at edge of talis]

Comment: So, to clarify: You have a normal pair of tzitzis, and you have a Tallis as well, and you’re proposing to add another string not already attached to either the Tzitzis or the Tallis and make a slip knot to attach the two sets of strings?

Comment: No, I’m asking whether the tzitzis on a tallis could be anchored to the edge of the tallis with a simple sewed thread. I’ll attach a picture to try and clarify what I’m asking.